# Заблокировать переход по direct ссылке

Tags: веб-программирование, frontend

подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать такую задачу и можно ли вообще.
Я хотел бы заблокировать открытие сайта при переходе по direct ссылкам, что бы сайт открывался только при переходе с выдачи google yandex etc. Как можно такое реализовать ?

Comment: заголовок `referer`  проверяйте на сервере. но чтобы ваш сайт в выдачу поисковика попал, надо ботам разрешить прямые входы.

Comment: А я смогу отследить когда переходят к примеру с телеграма или любого другого месседжера и как можно заблокировать эти переходы либо поставить заглушку

Comment: если вам нужно с гугла, то проверьте что в реферере указан гугл, всем остальным не показывайте.

Comment: А как сделать, что бы не показывать ? редирект?